# METIS serial graph partitioner

Tags: algorithm, graph

METIS graph partitioning algorithm is used for partitioning large graph. I have a graph which is actually a forest. I would like to know how METIS does the partitions in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, indeed, METIS can partition large graphs but that doesn't mean that it can not manage smaller graphs or different types of graphs.

Forest is only a special type of graph without cycles, where we can have disconnected parts...

As with any other type of graph, METIS is going to perform three level partitioning algorithm:

1. Coarsening (in your case, you have forest graph, so it may finish really quickly because that type of graph is probably going to have small number of edges or connections)
2. Initial partitioning
3. Uncoarsening + fine-grained balancing.

So basically, everything is going to work as with any type of graph.

And from my personal experience, I did find out that METIS didn't give me optimal results when working with disconnected graphs (and forest is disconnected graph), so I implemented my own logic for finding all groups of vertices that were connected and then used METIS to partition this group (which is connected)...

I recommend reading about METIS from [METIS library documentation](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/metis/metis/download).